# Resource id #3 to try to curl on centos?

Tags: php, curl

This is my code:

```
$base="http://www.google.co.in/";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $str;
print_r($curl);
```

I get an output like this Resource id #3 but curl function already worked but now it did not get a output.

Comment: That's because you are printing the value of the resource handle ($curl). Check the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php.

Comment: The `echo $str;` line should show the page source, it works fine here. Running `print_r` on a Curl object will always show a resource identifier.

Comment: ya ur correct iainn but i did not get page source